# Does unique factorisation hold for quiver algebras?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, quivers

Given a finite dimensional quiver algebra A=KQ/I. It can be (possibly) written as $A= B_1 \otimes_k B_2 ... \otimes_k B_r$ and the $B_i$ can not be decomposed into smaller algebras. Is this factorisation unique? (all quivers are assumed to be connected and have at least one arrow)

Answer (score 12):

In [Nüsken, M. "Unique tensor factorization of algebras", Math Ann. (1999) 315-341](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s002080050321) this is proved for $K$ of characteristic zero. As far as I know, it's still open in positive characteristic, although the same author proved some partial results in a later paper.